# Using htaccess to force a trailing slash before the ? with a query string?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, routes, pattern-matching

I have the following in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Check to see if the URL points to a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Trailing slash check
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

# Add slash if missing & redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# Check to see if the URL points to a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Send to index.php for clean URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This does work.  It hides index.php, and it adds a trailing slash... except when there is a query string.

This URL:

```
http://example.com/some-page
```

gets redirected to:

```
http://example.com/some-page/
```

but this URL:

```
http://example.com/some-page?some-var=foo&some-other-var=bar
```

does not get redirected.  I would like for the above to be sent to:

```
http://example.com/some-page/?some-var=foo&some-other-var=bar
```

I've reached the limits of my understanding of redirects with this.  If you have a working answer, I would really appreciate a walkthrough of what every line is doing and why it works.  Double bonus awesomeness for an explanation of why what I have right now doesn't work when there is a query string involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `[QSA]` to the end of the last Redirect rule to preserve the original query string  as below

```
# Send to index.php for clean URLs, preserve original query string
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

> a walkthrough of what every line is doing and why it works.

See my comments below

```
#turn mod_rewrite engine on.
RewriteEngine On
#set the base for urls here to /
RewriteBase /

### if the is not a request for an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

### and the URI does not end with a /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

### redirect and add the slash. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

### if the is not a request for an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# rewrite to index.php passing the URI as a path, QSA will preserve the existing query string
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I want to preserve the query string, not strip it. Your settings turn this: http:// example.com/some-page?test-var=foo to this: http:// example.com/some-page / I'm looking for this: http:// example.com/some-page/?test-var=foo

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you change this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^([^?]*)/($|\?)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) $1/ [L,R=301]
```

then it should do what you want.

The changes I made are:

- In both rewrite-condition and -rule, I changed `(.*)` and `^(.*)` to `^([^?]*)`, to ensure that, if there's a query-string, then it is not included in either regex. (`[^…]` means "any character that is not in `…`", so `[^?]` means "any character that is not a question mark".)
- In the rewrite-condition, I changed `$` to `($|\?)`, so as to match *either* end-of-URL *or* end-of-part-before-the-query-string.
- In the rewrite-rule, I dropped the `$`, since it was no longer needed.